# how to read image file in ruby

Tags: ruby

how to read image file in ruby suppose i open a jpg file like this

path="c:/image/aj.jpg"
File.open(path) do
  end

now how do i see this image file

Answer (score 7):

You can read arbitrary binary content

```
path = "/foo/bar/baz.jpg"
File.open(path, 'rb') {|file| file.read }
```

If you want to write this image to another..

```
File.open(path, 'rb') do |in|
  File.open("foo/bar/bob.jpg", 'wb') {|out| out.write(in.read) }
end
```

The binary flags are only required in Windows/DOS.

See the [IO class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html)

Comment: Define 'see', you'd need to open it up in your image viewing application. Assuming you're not talking about on a web page

Comment: You need to invoke `mspaint.exe` with the applicable command line flags. Do note though that I don't believe MSPaint handles JPG files. You'd need to search around google or perhaps submit another question regarding MSPaint and opening files via the command line.

Comment: @Lee-Jarvis  Could you hint out how in ruby after reading the file to output it with right header to browser?

Answer (score 1):

this is how to open mspaint in ruby

```
irb>print("mspaint  #{%x{path=c:/image/aj.jpg}}")# 
irb>print("mspaint  #{%x{mspaint a.jpg}}")# this is open your jpg file with mspaint
OR
irb>print("mspaint  #{%x{mspaint c:/image/a.jpg}}")#
```