# Reading a whole file in Ruby (possibly a bug)

Tags: ruby, io

In [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328495/how-to-read-whole-file-in-ruby) people recommend use File.read to read a whole file. But when I try to read png file (see fig. 1) I get only first line (see fig. 2). What am I doing wrong?
[image]
[image]

Comment: check this link [how to read image file in ruby][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334179/how-to-read-image-file-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `File.binread` to read binary data.

On certain operating systems (notably Windows), there is a difference between opening a file in "binary mode" (8-bit characters) and "text mode" (7-bit characters).   Because of this, these IO implementations can do things like detect end-of-file when there is a zero character, or mangle up characters outside of the ASCII range if you don't tell them to expect binary data.

If you open a file in Ruby, using mode "rb" instead of "r" will tell the OS that you expect binary data, and if it cares about that, it will do the right thing.   `File.binread()` opens the underlying file it will read from with that mode.